# Could not build wheels for pyjq | No such file or directory: 'autoreconf': 'autoreconf'

Tags: python, docker

I'm deploying a lambda function to `aws` using docker, the lambda function is using `pyjq` library, and it needs these libs to be installed:
`flex bison libtool make autoconf`
That's been said, an error happen when building the branch.

`No such file or directory: 'autoreconf': 'autoreconf'`

`Could not build wheels for pyjq which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`

```html
  /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig_install/include'

   /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 oniguruma.h oniggnu.h onigposix.h '/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig_install/include'

  make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig-6.9.0/src'

  make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig-6.9.0/src'

  Making install in test

  make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig-6.9.0/test'

  make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig-6.9.0/test'

  make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.

  make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.

  make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig-6.9.0/test'

  make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig-6.9.0/test'

  Making install in sample

  make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig-6.9.0/sample'

  make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig-6.9.0/sample'

  make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.

  make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.

  make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig-6.9.0/sample'

  make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig-6.9.0/sample'

  make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig-6.9.0'

  make[2]: Entering directory `/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig-6.9.0'

   /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig_install/bin'

   /usr/bin/install -c onig-config '/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig_install/bin'

   /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig_install/lib/pkgconfig'

   /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 oniguruma.pc '/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig_install/lib/pkgconfig'

  make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig-6.9.0'

  make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/pip-install-6ckq9ir8/pyjq/dependencies/onig-6.9.0'

  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'autoreconf': 'autoreconf'

  ----------------------------------------

  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyjq

ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyjq which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
```

Answer (score 8):

Based on the error message from your logs `error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'autoreconf': 'autoreconf'` you need to install following prerequisites.

Look at the pyjq [installation details](https://pypi.org/project/pyjq/).

> You will need flex, bison (3.0 or newer), libtool, make, automake and
> autoconf to build jq. Install them by Homebrew, APT or other way.

You can find the exact command for installation here: https://pypi.org/project/jq/

For Mac: `brew install autoconf automake libtool`

Comment: Works well to Ubuntu 20.04. 

apt install autoconf automake libtool  && pip3 install pyjq